# how to write a Deque data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, implementation, deque

how to write in Haskell a double-ended queue ("deque"). The data structure should have functions emptyDeque, front, back, removeFront, removeBack, addFront, addBack and isEmpty, and then display the double-ended queue between -> and <-.

this is the same but for a Queue:

```
module Queues (Queue, emptyQueue, front, remove, add, isEmpty)
   newtype Queue a = Queue [a]
   emptyQueue = Queue []
   front  (Queue (x:xs)) = x
   front (Queue []) = error("No front of empty queue")
   add (Queue xs) x = Queue (xs ++ [x])
   remove (Queue (x:xs)) = Queue xs
   remove (Queue []) = error("Nothing on queue to remove")
   isEmpty (Queue []) = True
   isEmpty (Queue (x:xs)) = False
   showElems [] = ""
   showElems (x:xs) = " " ++ (Prelude.show x) ++ (showElems xs)
   showQueue (Queue a) = "<" ++ (showElems a) ++ " >"
   instance (Show a) => Show (Queue a) where show = showQueue
```

I came up with is itt correct?

```
module Deques (Deque, emptyDeque, front, back, removeFront, removeBack , addFront, addBack, isEmpty)
newtype Deque a = Deque [a]
emptyQueue = Queue []
reverses (x:xs) = (reverses xs) ++ [x]
front (Deque (x:xs)) = x
front (Deque []) = error("No front of empty Deque")
back (Deque a) = front(reverse(a))
back (Deque []) = error("No back of empty Deque")
addBack (Deque xs) x = Deque (xs ++ [x])
addFront (Deque xs) x = Deque ([x] ++ xs)
removeFront (Deque (x:xs)) = Deque xs
removeFront (Deque []) = error("Nothing on Deque to remove")
removeBack (Deque a) = reverses(removeFront(reverses(a))
                 `
```

Comment: Check [the "deque" package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue) on Hackage, or read Chris Okasaki's paper, *[Simple and Efficient Purely Functional Queues and Deques](http://www.eecs.usma.edu/webs/people/okasaki/pubs.html#jfp95)*

Comment: yes it is I tried to do a queue thinking that it would be easier to start with that. isn't the deque the same than the queue but with adding: back, add back removeback.

Comment: @biz: Yes, but your Queue isn't really a queue if insertion costs O(n). Of course, fixing this is far from trivial, so you might still be on the right track, depending on the level you are studying at.

Comment: Try keeping two lists, one for the front, and one for the back.  Or just read Okasaki's paper.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos 
just started Haskel last week, oh so for exemple for O(n) back: 
back (Queue []) = error("No back of empty queue")                   
back (Queue (x:xs)) = (back Queue xs) ++ [x]

Comment: actually the function 'add' already adds at the back how to add at the front and how to display the back

Comment: is this correct? `addFront (Queue xs) x = Queue ([x] ++ xs)`

Comment: @biz: If you just started Haskell, then they're probably not expecting you to know Okasaki. Your `back` looks fine. Your `addFront` works (and efficiently), but there is no need to create and concatenate a list at the front; you can simply use `:`.

Comment: nice composite implementation of `removeBack`.  I am astounded by how many programmers don't reuse their own code.  Keep thinking like that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here my Final Deque implementation which works fine

```
module Deques (Deque, emptyDeque, front, back, removeFront, removeBack, addFront, addBack, isEmpty) where

    newtype Deque a = Deque [a]

    backwards (Deque []) = Deque []

    backwards (Deque a) = Deque( reverse a )

    emptyDeque = Deque []

    front (Deque (x:xs)) = x
    front (Deque []) = error("No front of empty Deque")

    back (Deque a) = front( backwards (Deque a))
    back (Deque []) = error("No back of empty Deque")

    addBack (Deque xs) x = Deque (xs ++ [x])
    addFront (Deque xs) x = Deque (x : xs)

    removeFront (Deque (x:xs)) = Deque xs
    removeFront (Deque []) = error("Nothing on Deque to remove")

    removeBack (Deque a) = backwards( removeFront( backwards (Deque a) ))
    removeBack (Deque []) = error("Nothing on Deque to remove")

    isEmpty (Deque []) = True
    isEmpty (Deque (x:xs)) = False

    showElems [] = ""
    showElems (x:xs) = " " ++ (Prelude.show x) ++ (showElems xs)
    showDeque (Deque a) = "<" ++ (showElems a) ++ " >"

    instance (Show a) => Show (Deque a) where show = showDeque
```

Comment: addBack is O(n), so building a large Deque by adding repeatedly to the back is O(n^2). Which is fine if you never do that I guess, but then what is the point of a Deque?

Answer (score 8):

Using lists to implement a Deque is not very efficient, but it can work. A few notes

Type errors aside, you seem to be writing function application in the style of other languages

```
front(reverse(a))
```

In Haskell, the parens are simply for grouping. The more Haskelly way to write that line would be

```
front (reverse a)
```

or even

```
front $ reverse a
```

Another note: adding something to the front of the list is very typical in Haskell

```
[x] ++ xs -- The weird way
x : xs -- The canonical way
```

Adding to the back of a list is ugly, though.

```
xs ++ [x] -- No better way for normal lists. This is inefficient
```

You're off to a fairly good start, but you should try to familiarize yourself with Haskell's unique paradigm and style. The first few chapters of [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) do a good job of this.